# driver de php no funcionan luego de actualizar xamp

Tags: xampp, php7, odbc

He actualizado XAMP a la última version, que viene con php 7.2.

he agregado los driver a xamp/php/ext/:

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts.dll
php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll
php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll
```

Ademas he configurado el php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_nts_x86
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_nts_x86
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86
```

Aquí mi código de conexión a SQL SERVER:

```
<?php

$serverName = "NOWAY\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"a1", "UID"=>"root", "PWD"=>"NOWAY");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
         echo "Conexión establecida.<br/>";
    }else{
         echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br/>";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
}
```

Finalmente tengo este error:

> Conexión no se pudo establecer. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP
>   [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpEBX.png) => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension
>   requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the
>   following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x86:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This
>   extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access
>   the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x86:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpEBX.png) => Array ( [0] =>
>   IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpEBX.png) => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver
>   specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source
>   name not found and no default driver specified ) )

También he verificado si tengo instalados los ODBC driver en windows

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden notar he atacado la situación de varias maneras y aun no logro dar con la solución. Como podría solucionar este error?

Comment: Creo que tu problema puede venir por la versión de ODBC driver que tenes instalada, para PHP 7.2 tiene que ser la versión 13.1 o la versión 17, puede ser que tengas instala otra version? Saludos

Comment: Excelente tenias razón.

Answer (score 0):

> Gracias al comentario de Leonardo Cabré procedí a descargar la versión
>   de ODBC 17.

instale y Vualá!!:

> Conexión establecida.
>   2017-04-18, 11:22
>   2017-04-18, 12:13
>   2017-04-18, 12:14
>   2017-04-19, 01:06
>   2017-04-19, 10:39

Gracias Leonardo Cabré.